# React [Auth0]: How to prevent redirect by changing the URL in the address bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router, auth0

I'm learning react and I've implemented `Auth0` authentication.
The issue I am facing is irrespective of the authentication is done or not. I'm able to change the URL and redirect to the respective pages.

Expected: User should not be able to access the page via changing the URL, URLs should be accessible only when the user has completed the authentication.

Main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const domain = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin + "/home"} //http://localhost:5173
    >
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import LoginButton from "./Components/LoginButton";
import LogoutButton from "./Components/LogoutButton";
import Profile from "./Components/Profile";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const App = () => {
  const { isLoading, error } = useAuth0();
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <main>
        <h1>Auth0 Login</h1>
        {error && <p>Authentication Error</p>}
        {!error && isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {!error && !isLoading && (
          <>
            <LoginButton />
            <LogoutButton />
            <Profile />
          </>
        )}
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Pages.jsx

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Kanji from "./Kanji";
import Result from "./Result";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import Logout from "./Logout";
import AuthRoute from "./AuthRoute";

function Pages() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="" />
      <AuthRoute path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
      <Route
        path="/kanji/:selectedLevel/:kanjiNumber/:quizType"
        element={<Kanji />}
      />
      <Route
        path="/result/:correctAnswers/:incorrectAnswers"
        element={<Result />}
      />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default Pages;
```

Profile.jsx

```
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import Pages from "../Pages/Pages";

const Profile = () => {
  const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  return (
    <div>
      {isAuthenticated && (
        <article>
          <h2>こんにちは {user?.nickname}</h2>
        </article>
      )}
      <Pages />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

Comment: The user can always put any URL they want in the address bar. It's the server's responsibility to not send information that requires authorization without one.

Comment: @Noam understood